# SQL Monthly Distinct Counts of 12 Month Rolling Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone have any examples in SQL of calculating a distinct count of UserIDs with contact dates across a 12 month period for each month of the year? So for example

```
Reporting Month October 2023 - count of distinct UserIDs with contacts between '20221101' AND '20231031'

Reporting Month November 2023 - count of distinct UserIDs with contacts between '20221201' AND '20231130'

Reporting Month December 2023 - count of distinct UserIDs with contacts between '20230101' AND '20231231'

Reporting Month January 2024 - count of distinct UserIDs with contacts between '20230201' AND '20240131'
```

I have been using distinct counts, each one as a separate query like below but need to really have the results for each reporting month in one SQL statement. It is blowing my mind as this is not just a simple add up of 12 months!

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)) AS October_23
FROM #TemporaryTable
WHERE ContactDate BETWEEN '20221101' AND '20231031'

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)) AS November_23
FROM #TemporaryTable
WHERE ContactDate BETWEEN '20221201' AND '20231130'
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in table text form (not screenshots, images, photos of screenshots on woden table etc)

Comment: Why would adding up the totals for the individual months give you the same total as for the entire 12 month period? You're looking for distinct counts here so what happens if users have contacts across multiple months? (That's probably why the 12 month period would have lower counts.)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help, as well as a proper explanation of the desired logic, as it's not clear. Do you want to get the rolling *sum* of the distinct counts, or do you want to get a rolling *distinct count* itself?

Comment: If you just want to run the same logic several times, you could either do a table that contains the start dates, and then join that with #TemporaryTable with join criteria ContactDate >= X.Date and ContactDate < dateadd(month, 12, X.Date). Or alternatively you could make a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to glue the results of your queries via the keyword of `union`, like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)) AS October_23
FROM #TemporaryTable
WHERE ContactDate BETWEEN '20221101' AND '20231031'

UNION

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)) AS November_23
FROM #TemporaryTable
WHERE ContactDate BETWEEN '20221201' AND '20231130'
```

Or, you could have a function that runs this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)) AS October_23
FROM #TemporaryTable
WHERE ContactDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(some_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND some_date
```

and then use it like:

```
SELECT some_date, myfunction(some_date)
FROM (
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( 2023, 10, 31 ) AS some_date
    UNION
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( 2023, 11, 31 ) AS some_date
) t
```

Comment: @Squirrel thanks for your comment, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)) AS October_23
FROM #TemporaryTable
WHERE ContactDate BETWEEN '20221101' AND '20231031'
GROUP BY YEAR(ContactDate), MONTH(ContactDate)
```